# How did physicists arrive at conclusion that the product of mass and velocity is equal to momentum?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, momentum, conservation-laws, definition

1. How did physicists arrive at conclusion that the product of mass and velocity is equal to [momentum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum)? What is the intuition behind $p=mv$? I had trouble finding any sources that state the actually derivation and intuition behind it.
2. As a follow up question, how did physics determine the equation for [kinetic energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_energy)?

Comment: How do you define momentum intrinsically?

Comment: No offence intended, but is momentum not simply just a definition rather than a derivation, it seems so intuitive to me, maybe because I am used to it. K.E., I guess was experimentally found, not so sure about that derivation, did you look through history of math/physics?

Comment: There is a duplicate for KE on this site, search Emilie du Chatelie

Comment: Have you done a search for *impetus* and/or John Buridan?

Comment: Momentum is DEFINED to be $mv$. The content of Newton's laws is that this random thing you defined is CONSERVED, thus useful.

Comment: Alternatively you could define momentum as the conserved Noether current associated with spacial translation symmetry, and prove it is equal to $mv$, but that's a little too complicated, and not really how things happened, historically.

Comment: And I'd give the same answer for kinetic energy. It's a randomly defined thing that is conserved, thus useful. Also could be defined as a conserved current associated with time invariance.

Comment: This question is better suited for the [History of Science and Mathematics](http://hsm.stackexchange.com) sister site.

Answer (score 5):

You've got it a little backwards - physicists first defined the quantity $m \cdot v$ because it quantified the amount of "motion" an object possessed. They named it "momentum".

Modern physics is primarily concerned with the quantity $m \cdot v$ (and the updated versions of that quantity in more recent frameworks of physics) **because it is conserved**. This makes it interesting and useful.

So, in short, there is no derivation of $p = m v$, because it's a definition. The quantity $m \cdot v$ was given a special name of its own because it is conserved, and therefore important.

There's an [interesting roundup about the history of the concept of momentum on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum#History_of_the_concept).

Comment: To emphasize the point here, no one in their right mind names some random computation and then goes looking for a use for the thing; they find that a particular quantity comes up repeatedly and has some interesting properties and *then* they give it a name.

Comment: @dmckee Quite true.

Answer (score 0):

Jean Bouridan, rector of the University of Paris around 1350, was the first philosopher, to my knowledge, who specifically stated the current concept of momentum.  He said that impetus was proportional to the product of weight and speed.

Momentum is considered to be the product of mass and velocity (velocity has direction as well as magnitude).  **Momentum is the tendency of a moving object to keep moving in the direction of its movement.**  It's a conserved quantity, which means it can be transferred from one object to another, and it always needs to be accounted for, as it can be neither created nor destroyed within a system.  For this reason, momentum is a very useful concept in the analysis of motion and collisions.

An object of great mass moving at great velocity is considerably more difficult to deflect or stop than an object of little mass moving at low velocity.  Momentum is directly proportional to mass and velocity.  That's the intuitive understanding of momentum.

Kinetic energy is the motion of an object.  It's measured in joules, one unit of which is the work done by one newton of force to move an object one meter in the direction of its motion.  A joule is also called a newton-meter when it is used to describe motion.

The equation for kinetic energy is derived from the work done by a force, which is derived from Newton's 2nd law of motion, **F = m * a**, where **F** is force, **m** is mass, and **a** is acceleration.

If work is done by a constant force to move an object the distance **s**, **Work = Fs = (ma)s**.  The distance **s = average velocity * time**.  The acceleration **a = (final velocity - initial velocity) / time**.  If you substitute these into the equation for work, you get:

W = m * [(final velocity - initial velocity) / time)] * [1/2 (initial velocity + final velocity) * time]

W = 1/2 * m * (final velocity)^2 - 1/2 * m * (initial velocity)^2

Kinetic energy is defined as **1/2 * m * velocity^2**.  (The derivation is from Serway, *Physics*, 1992)